# Double slit experiment with magnetic traps

Tags: double-slit-experiment, electromagnetic-induction, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

1. Is it possible to perform the following, modified double-slit experiment with single electrons/electron beam: The slits are separated in such a way, that each leads to a separate magnetic trap. The traps have oppositely directed magnetic fields, so that the electrons entering them move in circles in opposite directions.
2. If 1., is it possible to measure magnetic induction on the axes of both circles, produced by electrons moving around the circles? There should be enough of them to produce a current with measurable intensity and measurable induction.

Goal is to check whether electrons in separate traps remained in superposition by measuring magnetic induction, which will determine the current.

Comment: The answer: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/double-slit-experiment-with-magnetic-traps.986156/page-2#post-6317000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you „shoot“ one electron at a time, then assuming you can measure, what you described, you would only measure a magnetic induction on one side. I mean, if you measure it, it’s not in superposition anymore.